# Writing all outputs to a file (Python)

Tags: python, passwords, output, cracking

I have this code that should generate all possible combinations of digits and store them in a text file called Passwords4.txt. The issue here is that when I go to the text file it just shows 9999 instead of showing the numbers from 0000 to 9999.

```
import itertools
lst = itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=4) #Last part is equal to the password lenght
for i in lst:
    print ''.join(i)
f = open('Passwords4.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(''.join(i)) +'\n')
f.close()
```

Can someone explain what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `f.write` is not inside the loop, so it only happens once.

You probably want the `open()` before the loop, and your f.write in the loop (indented, same as `print`).

Answer (score 0):

Re:

```
for i in lst:
    print ''.join(i)
f = open('Passwords4.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(''.join(i)) +'\n')
```

By the time you open the file and write to it after the loop is finished), `i` has already been set to *just* the last result of the loop and that's why you're only getting `9999`.

A fix is to do the writes *within* the loop, with something like:

```
import itertools
lst = itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=4)
f = open('Passwords4.txt', 'w')
for i in lst:
    f.write(''. join(i) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the more Pythonic way of doing :

```
import itertools
lst = itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=4) #Last part is equal to the password lenght
with open('Passwords4.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in lst:
        print ''.join(i)
        f.write(str(''.join(i)) +'\n')
```

Python takes care of everything here ...

Comment: Should there be another indent here?

Comment: yes, by bad! Ill correct it. Thanks for picking up on that so quickly